# How can I create a MapRoute entry in ASP.NET MVC that only matches if there is no further path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, maproute

I'd like to create a MapRoute entry that will match "/Users", but won't match paths like "/Users/etc" or "/Users/etc/etc".

I have to also match "Users/{id}" (where ID is an int) and "Users/Me" (which are working OK). I have a constraint on ID (@"\d+").

Any idea how I'd go about that?

If I use the following, it matches all of the above:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Users", new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" });
```

Do I need to use a constraint? If so, what constraint should I use?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 (if it matters).

Comment: Default, `"Users"` will only match exactly `"Users"`. Do you have any other routes defined?

Comment: do you want something else to match when it is `/users/etc` else the what I suggest might work?

Comment: Just want to check, you want to match `users/11` and `users/ME` just not `users/EDIT/ME` or `users/EDIT/11` Do you still have the default MapRoute in place the {controller}/{action}/{id} one?

Comment: I don't want to match "Users/stuff" either, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `IgnoreRoute` method which you can use to ignore route, maybe the following would do what you need:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Users/{*pathInfo}");
```

**edit:**
Not really read up that much on constraints for MVC, but it looks like regex?

You mentioned your constraint of `\d+` in your update, this will match only digits, try `\S+` which will match everything bar spaces, problem is, it might match backslashes too!

A possible alternative would be `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: this goes in the global asax, with the rest of your `RegisterRoutes`

Comment: Yes, this looks like it might work. I'll try it out just now.

Comment: Hmmm. No, that seems to prevent me accessing "/Users" as well.

Comment: I didn't think about a constraint in IgnoreRoute. So, I tried putting 'new { pathRemainder = ".+" }' in their. Seems like that might have worked. I'll test it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

the order in which you specify routes in MVC is the important part - the system works its way down the Routes and finds the first match that it needs to that satisfies

therefore the general routes need to be further down the list

the order in this case our be

- /Users/etc/etc
- /Users/etc
- /Users (as a catch all)

hope this helps?

more information about routing can
   be found here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: +1 for good, correct, information, but it doesn't directly answer the question.  Is there a way to have a route match `/Users`/ but not `/Users/etc`/ when nothing else matches `/Users/etc` first?

Answer (score 0):

Here is exact  solution:

Just replace places of  `id` and `action` in `url` parameter, you got it:

`"Users/{action}/{id}"`  => `"Users/{id}/{action}"`

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Users",
"Users/{id}/{action}",
 new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Even with this:

`id = UrlParameter.Optional`

you can have `yourapp.com/Users` or `yourapp.com/Users/whatever`

referring answer [How do I change the order of routes.MapRoute in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542345/how-do-i-change-the-order-of-routes-maproute-in-mvc3)