# How do I change the order of routes.MapRoute in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do I change the order of the url parameter when registering routes in global.asax.cs?

I registered the route like so: (Note: I also have the default MVC3 route registered as well)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "SurveyWizard",
  "survey/{id}/{action}",
  new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "AddQuestions" });
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult AddQuestions(int id)
{
  if(id < 1 || id == null)
    //Redirect somewhere  
  var survey = _surveyService.GetSurveyById(id);
  //other controller logic
  return View(survey);
}
```

When I type the url .../survey/1/AddQuestions the resource can't be found.  When I run a route debugger the route shows as valid.

Is this even possible in MVC3?  I know in Restful WCF, you can structure routes like this no problem.  In the grand scheme of things I could probably live with {controller}/{action}/{id}, but I believe in using verbs only when necessary and in my case the correct url should be structured per my example above.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route is missing a default controller, like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "SurveyWizard",
  "survey/{id}/{action}",
  new { controller="Survey", action="AddQuestions" });
```

Another point you should be aware of is that the default rote should be the last one...

Comment: Thanks CD.  That was it!  I accidentally omitted my controller from my code.  It was the order of the default route that was the problem.  Thanks again.